# Can I safely switch computer on LAN?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, hosting

So recently I started playing a minecraft modpack with my brother on minecraft 1.7.10. So I created a world and opened it to LAN so he could join. Now I'll give you the question:

There is PC A (PC hosting LAN) and B (PC joining LAN). And then there is account 1 (me) and 2 (my brother).
So we started off with account 1 on PC A and account 2 joining on PC B. Now account 2 wants to play on PC A because this PC is better. This means account 1 will play on PC B. Will we spawn in with the right progress (inventory, achievements, health, hunger, location, ...) if we do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

**Yes.**

You will spawn with the exact same progress you had before if you play on the same world, and if you both keep your usernames (for ex. you used to use xyz username on pc x, you should login with xyz on pc y too), however as you will change your computers, the person who is OP will change to the person who is on the PC which is the host.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. As of command permissions I don't really care because the world wasn't created with command permissions and you can always select allow cheats when you open to LAN.

Comment: @Florens Don't forget to hit the green "accept" button if this answer answered your question and helped you :)

Comment: Yes, I know. But last time I had to wait 4 minutes. You were that fast in answering. ;)

Comment: @Florens no problem, I like to answer questions quickly as this way people can see it faster :)

Comment: Sorry but it seems this is incorrect. My brother spawned in with my stuff.

Comment: @Florens You should both login with your old username (the one you used to use on the other computer). Will edit answer to clarify.

Comment: Yes we did log out and logged back in with our own username.

Comment: @Florens that sounds like a bug. Minecraft world files contain infos on account-side, not op/user-side. What is your minecraft version? edit  1.7.10